# how to create a custom skin in jCarousel

Tags: 7, javascript

I want to create a custom skin in jCarousel. I have seen this website http://timonweb.com/how-create-custom-skin-jcarousel-drupal-7, but I don't want to create any new module. How to do it in a simple way? I had tried creating a new skin folder inside the skins directory of jCarousel module, but it didn't worked.

Comment: Any chance you got it solved? I have a similar problem, where I do not want to manually code the carousel, just to use the Views plugin style settings, but I cannot get it to "install" (notice) my custom skin.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after a moment of googling, I can say that apparently you cannot go without writing a tiny module, but even though I myself have been reluctant to write YABM (Yet Another... Module), it took me about 5 minutes.
Have a glimpse at [this article](http://timonweb.com/how-create-custom-skin-jcarousel-drupal-7), copy and paste the code, change the skin name occurrences and there you go - your skin recognized with clean hands. Thanks to http://timonweb.com.

Comment: yes you can do in this way. but you can also override css. thers no problem with override css

Comment: The idea of a custom module is that you can use it with any theme.
If you change your theme, you must re-write the override of all your css. I think that it's better to have independent css for jcarousel or similar.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to create any module. I used a Zen subtheme and used the navigation.css file (or any other .css file you like). There's a Drupal convention to write CSS settings in an appropriate CSS file, but I am not much familiar with this convention. Its best if you create your own CSS file custom.css and write all the overriding CSS properties there.
In that navigation.css file I wrote, there are the CSS settings for jcarousel, or you may say I override the previous jcarousel skin settings. I used the tango skin, and override the CSS settings in navigation.css. You may create custom pointers and create an image sprite for those pointers.

Comment: Oh well, it all depends on the approach. I like clean solutions and I just wanted to have the skin easily available in the Views settings. My experience shows that overriding entire skins or stylesheets sooner or later will bring up garbage side effects from the things one neglected to check. Overriding also translates into a big overhead of redundant data and browser processing. Glad to have written that tiny module anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A quick glimpse at the sites/all/modules/jcarousel/skins/default/jcarousel-default.css file gave me a good idea of what already was there. I wrote all my custom CSS straight into my theme's CSS file and used the Default theme in Views jCarousel, then just used CSS overrides to get it to look just the way I wanted it.

[image: screenshot of my style overrides on top of the default theme]